# Python IDE (Visual Studio Code and PyCharm) Issues with "gi" Library

Tags: terminal, python, tty, python3

I'm having a specific problem with two Python IDEs, Visual Studio Code and PyCharm, which I hope to get some guidance on. The problem is related to the "gi" library. I'm running Python on Linux Mint 21.2, and here's a summary of my situation:

Problem Description:
I have a Python program that uses the "gi" library. When I run it in my normal terminal, it works perfectly.
However, when I run the same program in both Visual Studio Code and PyCharm, I encounter an error indicating that the "gi" library cannot be found.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
I've ensured that I'm using the same Python interpreter in all three environments.
I've checked that the "gi" library is installed, and it's indeed present.
I've tried setting the environment variables and Python paths in the IDEs to match my system environment, but the problem persists.

I'm looking for advice on how to resolve this issue so that I can work seamlessly with the "gi" library in both Visual Studio Code and PyCharm. (btw I'm posting this here because I got banned from asking questions on stack overflow, because my questions "weren't received well by the community")

Comment: I'm no longer gonna check if anything is added here.